# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.redhat.ceylon.compiler.java.runtime.tools.Options

Tags: vert.x, ceylon

Using Ceylon IDE 1.2.1 and Vert.x 3.2.1:

```
import io.vertx.ceylon.core {
    vertx_=vertx
}

shared void run() { 
    value vertx = vertx_.vertx();
}
```

module has

```
shared import io.vertx.ceylon.web "3.2.1";
```

Run as Ceylon Java Application, results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory: Provider io.vertx.lang.ceylon.CeylonVerticleFactory could not be instantiated
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.loadVerticleFactories(DeploymentManager.java:56)
at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.<init>(DeploymentManager.java:51)
at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.<init>(VertxImpl.java:139)
at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.<init>(VertxImpl.java:114)
at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.<init>(VertxImpl.java:110)
at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:34)
at io.vertx.core.Vertx.vertx(Vertx.java:79)
at io.vertx.ceylon.core.vertx_.vertx(vertx_.java:51)
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/redhat/ceylon/compiler/java/runtime/tools/Options
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.redhat.ceylon.compiler.java.runtime.tools.Options from [Module "io.vertx.lang.ceylon:3.2.1" from Ceylon ModuleLoader: RootRepositoryManager: FileContentStore: /Users/axel/.ceylon/cache]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
... 45 more
```

Any ideas? I can't remember anything like this from the 1.2.0 Ceylon IDE release, so I am guessing there's a change there. Vert.x 3.2.0 gives the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because Vert.x 3.2 is only compatible with Ceylon 1.2, not Ceylon 1.2.1. There will be a new version in the coming days to fix that.

Comment: Works now with Ceylon 1.2.2 and Vert.x 3.2.2, thank you very much